# Simulate remote notification on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to debug remote push notifications on the client without the need for the server to send me an actual push notification.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also fork and build the OS X app yourself: [Pusher](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher)

I've used it myself to test how apps handle APNS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible , you need a php file to trigger push notification. 
open the folder where your php file contains in terminal, and type the below command.

```
php fileName.php
```

[Here is the sample php file](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SimplePush.zip)

You need to add your clients UDID in this php file. For that print the UDID on `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` method then using any [remote logging SDK](https://logentries.com/) you can take clients UDID.
Aslo see [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) for detailed tutorial